# Consulta Mysql usando INNER JOIN com HAVING

Tags: mysql, query

Possuo duas tabelas no Mysql.

A primeira tabela `curriculo` possui como ID `cur_codigo`.

A segunda tabela `envio` possui `env_codigo` como ID e `env_curriculo` como chave estrangeira de `cur_codigo`.

A tabela `envios` refere-se a quantidade de envios realizados para cada um dos currículos cadastrados. Sendo assim, cada currículo possui uma quantidade diferente de envios registrados na tabela `envios`.

Estou tentando criar uma consulta para **exibir apenas a quantidade total** de currículos, cuja **quantidade de envios seja inferior a 3**, no entanto, não consegui fazê-la retornar o resultado esperado.

O detalhe é que esta consulta trata-se de uma subquery, ou seja, precisa retornar apenas uma linha. E com o group by, está sendo retornando um erro, pois, como sabemos, ele retorna mais de uma linha.

Segue abaixo a consulta:

```
select 
(select count(cur_codigo) from curriculo CUR INNER JOIN envio ENV ON 
CUR.cur_codigo=ENV.env_curriculo
group by cur_codigo
having count(ENV.env_codigo)<3) as qtdeCurriculo
from curriculo
```

A saída deveria retornar -> 5

Segue código SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27f371/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cláusula `HAVING` é usada para restringir os resultados retornados pela cláusula `GROUP BY`

Então foi adicionado o código do curso, e a cláusula `GROUP BY`:

```
select cur_codigo, count(cur_codigo) from curriculo CUR INNER JOIN envio ENV ON 
CUR.cur_codigo=ENV.env_curriculo
group by cur_codigo
having count(cur_codigo)<3
```

Dessa forma retornando conforme esperado:

**[Resultado]**

```
| cur_codigo | count(cur_codigo) |
|------------|-------------------|
|        300 |                 2 |
|        400 |                 1 |
|        600 |                 1 |
|        700 |                 2 |
|        800 |                 2 |
```

---

**Edit:**
Podemos fazer uma subconsulta, e somente fazer um `count`.

```
SELECT count(1)
  FROM (SELECT count(cur_codigo)
          FROM curriculo CUR
         INNER JOIN envio ENV ON CUR.cur_codigo=ENV.env_curriculo
         GROUP BY cur_codigo
        HAVING count(cur_codigo)<3) qtdCursos
```

Comment: Oi Davi, obrigado pela resposta. Agora que percebi que faltou eu incluir um detalhe na minha pergunta, pois essa consulta trata-se de uma subquery. Sendo assim, preciso que o resultado retorne apenas uma linha. Já editei a minha pergunta. =D

Comment: Visualmente falando como retornaria somente 1 linha? separado por virgula? Exemplo: `300x2, 400x1, 600x1, 700x2, 800x2` ? Explica melhor como vc quer a saida, se possivel edita sua pergunta.

Comment: blz, vou editar. A saída deveria retornar o número 5, que são exatamente as 5 linhas que você postou aí na sua resposta.

Comment: Entendi, editei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado, Davi! =D